# Select room availability in same table between 2 dates (using SQL)

Tags: php, mysql, select

I would like to search for room availability.

Table structure:

[image: table structure (roomAvailability)]

How to fetch only that field where room available in particular date, like in pic there are rid(13).

Comment: This question is incomprehensible.

Answer (score -1):

As I understand, you want `rid` where `noofRooms` is greater than 0
In that case you need to use [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) to group rows with same `rid`.
Like so:

```
SELECT `rid`,`noofRooms` FROM `roomAvailability` GROUP BY `rid` HAVING `noofRooms`>0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but need some more code i think because when i use your code, it execute  like                                                                                    rid : 11, 12, 13 || noofRooms 3, 1, 2, but i want only rid: 13